# VS2019 extension using IDebugEventCallback2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2019

I created a new VS extension using VS2019 16.1.6.
 and I added this using statement

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop;
```

and added the interface IDebugEventCallback2 to my class

```
public sealed class VSIXProject1Package : AsyncPackage, IDebugEventCallback2
```

Not I get the error:

> error CS0433: The type 'IDebugEventCallback2' exists in both 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop, Version=8.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.InteropA, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

How can I get rid of this error? Or is there an other way to react to debugger events than using IDebugEventCallback2?

edit:
Problem reported to Microsoft:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/651199/vs2019-extension-using-idebugeventcallback2.html

Comment: After my check, this issue only occurs in VS2019 while VS2017 works well. Because in VS2017, it only reference necessary packages while VS2019 will reference much more packages than what VS2017 does, which causes the conflict. You can try my workaround to resolve this issue, and after that I suggest you can report this issue to [developercommunity/problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=8). The system will help direct this issue to the correct product team.

Comment: Thank you, Lance Li! I have reported the problem.

Comment: You can share the link in question, people who interested in it or meet similar issue will vote and follow it:) And glad to know that my answer makes some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS2019 uses [PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) format to manage nuget packages for VSIX project.

And by default it will reference `Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK` and `Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools` package.Also, since `Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK` package have dependencies on many other packages, this project will also reference those packages.

See this simple structure:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK
   ......(other dependencies)
   --Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop
      --Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop
   --Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop.10.0
      --Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.InteropA
   ......(11.0,12.0,14.0,15.0)
   --Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop.16.0
      --Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.InteropA
```

So it's clear this issue results from the VSIX project adds reference to both `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.InteropA`.
These two assemblies have the same namespace `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop`, and all have `IDebugEventCallback2` Interface. I think it's why causes this issue.

**As a workaround:**

Normal we can use [extern alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias) for this situation. But it hasn't supported for `PackageReference` format yet. Fortunately I found a good hint from [gertjvr](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4989#issuecomment-311042085). So all we need is:

Unload the project=>Edit the xxx.csproj=>Add the content below into the project file:

```
  <Target Name="ChangeAliasesOfStrongNameAssemblies" BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences;ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)' == 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop'">
        <Aliases>signed</Aliases>
      </ReferencePath>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

You can change the `ReferencePath` to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.InteropA` if you want to use the Interface from this assembly. It depends on your need.